# Proving this polynomial is identically zero, as a result of this contour integration

Tags: complex-analysis

**Problem:** Let $p$ be a polynomial and suppose that $$ \int_{C_1(0)} p(z) \overline{z}^k dz = 0, \qquad k=0, 1, 2, \ldots $$
Prove that $p \equiv 0$. 
(Here $C_1(0)$ denotes the unit circle centered at origin).

**My attempt:** I parametrize the unit circle as $z(t) = e^{it}$. Then we have that $$ \int_0^{2 \pi} p(e^{it}) e^{-ikt} i e^{it} dt = i \int_0^{2 \pi} p(e^{it}) e^{i (1-k) t} dt = 0 $$ for all $k > 0$. I let $p(z) = a_n z^n + a_{n-1} z^{n-1} + \ldots + a_1 z + a_0$. I want to show that all the coefficients are zero. With this notation I have $$ i \int_{0}^{2 \pi} ( a_n e^{int} + a_{n-1} e^{(n-1)it} + \ldots + a_1 e^{it} + a_0) e^{i(1-k) t} dt =0. $$ I'm not sure how to show that it follows from this that all coefficients are zero. I think I need to use Cauchy's theorem somehow. Maybe I need to pick a specific $k$?

Comment: Hint: the integral of $e^{i m t}$ from $0$ to $2\pi$ is either $2 \pi$ or $0$ depending on whether $m = 0$ or not.

Answer (score 3):

The basic fact is that
$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}e^{i(m-k)\theta}d\theta=\cases{0&if $m\ne k$\cr 1&if $m=k$}$$
 So, your integral gives $a_{k-1}=0$.

Answer (score 1):

For $k=2$, we have 
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{2\pi}p(e^{it})e^{-it}dt&=0\\
\sum_{l=0}^{n}\int_{0}^{2\pi}a_{l}e^{i(l-1)t}dt&=0\\
2\pi a_{1}&=0\\
a_{1}&=0,
\end{align*}
can you proceed for other coefficients?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative method:

**Hint** The quantity $\overline{p(z)}$ is a linear combination of the monomials $\bar{z}^k$.

> ...which implies that $\int_{C_1(0)} p(z) \bar z \overline{p(z)} \,dz = 0$, but converting to a line integral using the usual parameterization gives $\int_0^{2 \pi} |p(e^{i \theta})|^2 d\theta = 0$.

Comment: Well, you need to adjust a little bit, because there remains som $dz$.

Comment: I meant that you need to say $$\int_{C(0)}p(z)\overline{zp(z)}dz=i\int_{0}^{2\pi}|p(e^{i\theta})|^2d\theta=0$$

Comment: @OmranKouba Either I misunderstand you or you have something in mind other the solution that I do: Substituting $\overline{p(z)} = \bar a_n \bar z^n + \cdots + \bar a_1 \bar z + \bar a_0$ and using linearity gives
$$\int_{C_1(0)} |p(z)|^2 \,dz = \int_{C_1(0)} p(z) \overline{p(z)} \,dz = \sum_{i = 0}^n \bar a_i \int_{C_1(0)} p(z) \bar z^k \,dz = 0 .$$ So, $p(z)$ takes the value zero everywhere on the image of $C_1(0)$, and in particular on infinitely many points. But the only polynomial with infinitely many roots is $p(z) = 0$.

Comment: If I understand well the definition of complex integration you have $$0=\int_{C_1(0)}|p(z)|^2dz=i\int_0^{2\pi}|p(e^{i\theta})|^2 \color{red}{ e^{i\theta}}d\theta$$ and from this you cannot conclude that $p(z)$ vanishes on the unit circle, sorry.

Comment: @OmranKouba Yes, of course---thank you for clarifying, and for the comment---it's most helpful. I've adjusted the hint in my answer to fix the issue like you say.

Comment: You are wellcome.